# How to Fetch href links in Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, href, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the link from a button. If I click the button, it opens a new tab and I can't navigate in it. So I thought I'd scrape the link, go to it via webdriver.get(link) and do it that way since this will be a background program. I cannot find any tutorials on this using the most recent version of selenium. This is in Python

I tried using

```
wd.find_element("xpath", 'xpath here')
```

but that just scrapes the button title. Is there a different tag I should be using?

I've also tried just clicking the button but that opens a new tab and I don't know how to navigate on it, since it doesn't work by default and I'm still fairly new to Chromedriver.

I can't use beautifulsoup to my knowledge, since the webpage must be logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the href attribute of the button. If your code gets the right button you can just use

```
button.get_attribute("href")
```

Of course if you get redirected using Javascript this is a different story, but since you didn't specify I will assume my answer works

Comment: I know that clicking it redirects to a new tab. I can try using that. Would that just be identifying the button and using that? I've never used that code before.

Comment: Yes you need to identify the button first

Comment: Would I just do that via that button1 = wd.find_element("xpath", button's xpath) like i do to set up to click it? I'm guessing from there its button1_get_attribute("href")?

Comment: Yes and if the button is using a href attribute to send you to a _blank target then you can extract the link and navigate to it using driver.get

Comment: So i went ahead and tried that. the get_attribute is not even in selenium now? I think I'm running the new version

Answer (score 0):

You can use swith_of function to manage multiple windows(tabs) in same test case session

```
driver.switch_to.window(name_or_handler)
```

An extra information: If you want to get attribute value from element, you can use get_attribute() function

```
link_value = driver.find_element(By, selector).get_attribute("href")
```

P.S: example code written in Python. If you use another language, you can use equivalent Selenium functions for them.

Comment: @Roo if the answer resolved your issue accept it. Judging by your comment it did